# Change a link to image

Tags: php, json, drupal

I need help on this situation.
I'm currently imported data from a JSON, and for the photos field, all I get was link to that image.

Is there any module/other method that can change 
this

```
http://example.com/images/abc-123.jpg
```

to

```
<img src="http://example.com/images/abc-123.jpg" />
```

Or let them direct read the link and change to image display?

Additional info:

Here's the structure for the field display.

```
<div class="field">
    <div class="field-items">
        <div class="field-item even">
            <p>
                <a href="http://example.com/images/abc-123.jpg">http://example.com/images/abc-123.jpg
                </a>
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="field-item odd">
            <p>
                <a href="http://example.com/images/efg-123.jpg">http://example.com/images/efg-123.jpg
                </a>
            </p>
        </div>
        ........... for multiple link
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where are you receiving this JSON data? In your PHP code or HTML/Javascript side?

Comment: HTML/Javascript side, using JSON parser module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are processing the JSON data in Javascript, then..

```
var image_url = data.image_url; // assuming data.image_url gives us the url to the image
var html_for_image = "<img src='" + image_url + "' />";
// if you are using jQuery
$('#image_element_placeholder').html(html_for_image);
// else if you are using plain JS
var placeholder = document.getElementById('image_element_placeholder');
placeholder.innerHTML = html_for_image;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have to do these at the JSON source? Or at the destination(drupal)?

Answer (score 0):

try this, no need method

example

the link is in variable

```
$link = http://example.com/images/abc-123.jpg

echo "<img src=" . $link . " />";
```

Comment: works on single data, but multiple data with many pages. not that convenient.